# TypeError: string indices must be integers (python) about object storage

Tags: pandas, function, syntax-error, typeerror, yahoo-finance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w48KG.png)I'm a beginner at Python. I don't know why the error occurred. Please help me..
I want to create a form that stores data after creating a variable by using the for statement.

Comment: You should make simple example with text or code  instead of image. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: 한국분이라서 제가 답변을 좀 달아드리자면 이렇게 질문하시면 답변을 얻기 쉽지 않고요.  본인의 작업도 올리실 필요없고 그냥 copy하실 수 있는 간단한 example을 만들고 원하는 output도 간단한 example로 만들어서 어떻게 얻을 수 있을지 물어보시는게 답변 얻기에 빠르실거에요. 데이터도 없는데 선생님의 작업 흐름을 따라가서 선생님의 코드를 읽고 코드만으로 어떤 에러가 발생했는지 알려줘야 한다는건데 답변자들이 답변달고 싶지 않죠. 일단 제가 추측하기로는 리스트로 추정되는 data_bundle이라는 변수로 반복문을 돌리시는데 그 j가 string이라서 key로는 인덱싱이 불가능하다라는 에러 메세지네요. 반복문을 돌리는data_bundle의 각 요소가 데이터프레임이나 딕셔너리 같은 key로 인덱싱이 되는 자료형이 아닌거죠.

Comment: In summary, there is something in `data_bundle` that is not dataframe

Comment: @PandaKim 처음이라 잘 몰랐는데 알려주셔서 진짜 감사합니다. 다음부터는 알려주신 형식대로 올려보도록 하겠습니다..! https://muzukphysics.tistory.com/entry/%ED%8C%8C%EC%9D%B4%EC%8D%AC-%EC%9E%90%EB%8F%99-%EB%B3%80%EC%88%98-%EC%83%9D%EC%84%B1-for%EB%AC%B8%EC%9C%BC%EB%A1%9C-%EB%8F%99%EC%A0%81-%EB%B3%80%EC%88%98-%EC%83%9D%EC%84%B1%ED%95%98%EA%B8%B0-Python 저가 이 사이트 보고 따라하려고 했었는데 계속 오류가 나오네요. 제가 이해한 바로는 format에 key를 넣고 make_diff라는 함수에 value값을 넣는 걸로 이해 했는데 계속 안되네요